# SQLiteDatabase onUpgrade issue

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to know .

I have one Table

```
create table User (userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username text,address text)
```

and i am creating this table on `onCreate()`

and inserting the value.

```
INSERT into User (username,address) VALUES('noname','xyz')
```

**output-**`username--noname address--xyz`

and on `onUpgrade()`

i added one column in above table

```
 ALTER TABLE User ADD COLUMN City text
```

and insert value  `INSERT into User(City) VALUES('delhi')`

when i launch the app the output its showing.

**output-**   `username--null address--null city--delhi`

why its showing `null` for both column .even i did not `drop` the table

it should show something like this

**output-** `username--noname address--xyz city--delhi`

please clarify this behavior of `onUpgrade`

like this:-

```
@Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion)

        {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE User ADD COLUMN City TEXT");
            db.execSQL("INSERT into User (City) VALUES(delhi)");
        }
```

Comment: have you deleted old database?

Comment: no. i just added new column..see method onUpgrade()

Comment: check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5688175/1567588

Comment: Yes delete app and run again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what the `INSERT` command does, it creates entirely new records.

To update the values in existing records, use the `UPDATE` command:

```
UPDATE User SET City = 'Delhi' WHERE username = 'noname'
```